# Реализация аутентификации на микросервисной архитектуре

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Пишу приложение на микросервисах и столкнулся с одной проблемой, а именно аутентификацией пользователей. Бэк на ноде, фронт на реакте + nginx, для общения с сервисами использую брокер NATS. Немного поразмыслив придумал только один способ реализации аутентификации, а именно использовать JWT, хранить его в куки пользователя, а с фронта слать его в заголовках вместе с ключом API, а в гейтвее проверять его наличие. Но тут выливается еще одна проблема, как правильней реализовать его валидацию, делать под это отдельный сервис, где будет валидация, выдача и рефреш, или же написать это все в сервисе авторизации. Есть может кто сталкивался с аутентификацией на микросервисах, есть какие еще варианты решения проблемы? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Выдача и рефреш — в отдельном микросервисе, а валидацию каждый микросервис делает самостоятельно, ведь в этом и есть смысл JWT

Comment: Окей, а по поводу передачи самого токена на бэк, есть какие еще варианты, которые можно рассмотреть, помимо того, которого я уже описал выше?